# I am having trouble understanding the Iterable class then with the .map syntax. can you put this in a simple language?

Tags: flutter, dart, iterable

I am getting it makes ListTiles on a new route, but I am having trouble understanding the syntax. Please, can you explain in simple language what's going on here?

```
void _pushSaved() {
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = _saved.map(
        (WordPair pair) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              pair.asPascalCase,
              style: _biggerFont,
            ),
          );
        },
      );
      final List<Widget> divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
        context: context,
        tiles: tiles,
      ).toList();

      return Scaffold(
        // Add 6 lines from here...
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: divided),
      ); // ... to here.
    },
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterables in Dart (List, Map, Set, etc.) have "functional style" methods that apply common types of loops to their elements. `map()` runs a function on each element of the iterable and whatever that function returns is collected into a new iterable.

```
List<int> squares(List<int> numbers) {
  return numbers.map((number) => number * number).toList();
}
```

It "maps" an `Iterable<Type1>` to an `Iterable<Type2>`. Although they can be the same type like in my example.